# dayClick and eventClick function not working

Tags: fullcalendar

I have inserted some new functions in my js but `dayClick` and `eventClick` don't work. The calendar is able to load properly though.

Any idea why the dayclick and eventclick in the following code is not working?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: '',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        allDayDefault: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        firstHour: 9,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        },

        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    window.location = "http://www.domain.com?start=" + calEvent.start;

},

        select: function(start, end) {

            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    },
                    false // make the event "stick"
                );

                var startDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
                var endDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{url}ajaxpost/add',
                    data: {
                        startDate: startDateString,
                        endDate: endDateString,
                        eventTitle: title                            
                    },
                    dateType: 'json',
                    success: function (resp) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                    }
                });
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: "{url}ajaxget/data",
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the "select" callback and the "dayClick" callback together as there is a conflict between the two. You can use datepicker to accomplish the gotoDate function to accomplish the same thing.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/02/linking-jqueryui-datepicker-and-fullcalendar.aspx

As for the eventClick Im not sure why it is not working, but it is easier to place the url in the database the call it in the events and just set it as the property "url: www.somesite.com/sdfjkiwe"

As a side note, It would probably wor better if you didn't use renderEvent to display your event. Try using the event function found here to use your ajax call within it.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Comment: You can use select and dayClick together although you are a bit limited. For example I use the `dayClick` callback to switch to `agendaDay` `if (allDay == true)` to be able to switch from month and week view to day if the whole day was clicked. This works but you have to click on the "all-day" area in week view.